# why does this work in jstl with hashmaps?

Tags: java, hashmap

why does display what i want:

```
   <c:forEach var="temp" items="${AvailableLessonBean.lessons['description']}">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <c:out value="${temp}"/>
                            </td>
```

which displays in a html table:

Description Start Date  Start Time  End Time    Level   Make Booking
Snowboarding for dummies
Advanced Carving Techniques
How to not fall off the draglift
Gnarliness Extreeeeeeeme
Parallel turns
How to splint a broken leg with a s
Cross-country techniques
Aerobatics
Intermediate Slalom

and this does not display anything but an exception:

```
    <c:forEach var="temp" items="${AvailableLessonBean.lessons}">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <c:out value="${temp['description']}"/>
                            </td>
```

I have no hair left because of this!!

Comment: what is the type of lessons?

Comment: Map<String, List<String>> for lessons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, you didn't tell us what these objects are, which makes it impossible to answer. Hopefully for you, I remember the data structure from a previous question.

So, `AvailableLessonBean.getLessons()` returns a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

In your first snippet, you iterate over `AvailableLessonBean.lessons['description']`. What this EL code does is that it gets the value associated with the key "description" in the map:

```
map.get("description")
```

that works fine. It returns a `List<String>`. It iterates over that list, and stores the current element of the list in a variable named `temp`. And at each iteration, it prints `temp`. This is thus equivalent to the following Java code:

```
List<String> list = availableLessonBean.getLessons().get("description");
for (String temp : list) {
    out.println(temp);
}
```

In the second snippet, you're iterating over the map itself. The JSTL specifies that when you iterate over a map, you iterate over all the entries of the map. Each entry has a key and a value. So the iteration is equivalent to doing, in Java:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> temp : availableLessonBean.getLessons().entrySet()) {
    ...
}
```

But then you're trying to access `temp["description"]`. That doesn't make any sense. `temp` is a Map Entry. A Map Entry has a key and a value. That's all. In this case, the key is a `String` and the value is a `List<String>`.

Comment: but does it display the descriptions key in a list like i mentioned and now i want to do the same for the others but it display what i want

Comment: I don't underdtand anything of that comment. My advice: define your own classes instead of using maps of lists. And start programming the iteration logic in Java. Once it compiles and does what you want, then translate it to JSTL.

Comment: Available Lesson is part of a bean so i am using a class

Comment: could you please suggest a potential solution as im at a dead end now